# rest API - UFT authorization with Basic token

Tags: rest, hp-uft, uft-api

I tried to authorize REST API in UFT, the authentication does not seem to as easy as I supposed with other tools. Any recommendation how to use this tool?

Comment: You need to provide more details to get good response. How are you setting up REST API in UFT? Have you provided `Username` and `password` using `Add Resource` through `Add REST Service`?

Comment: Hi There. Yes those steps are taken (Add Resource, Add Rest Service)- scenario is I have Basic token for "api.**.com". I need various results using this token for example, api.***.com/v1/transactions/{customerid}. I have no clue how I use this token in UFT. Any thoughts?